# prove distributive law of multiplication over subtraction.

Tags: real-analysis

The first section of the question was, 
$\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}  $ prove $a(-b) = (-a)b = -ab$

I did it as follows
 $a+(-a) = 0 \\   
b[a+(-a)] = 0\\
ab + (-a)b =0\\
\therefore (-a)b= -ab\\
And \ similarly for \\a(-b) = -ab$

Is it correct?
And the next section asks to prove distributive law of multiplication over subtraction and I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems correct. However, you may want to be a bit more careful. For example,

$$b[a + (-a)] = b0 = 0$$

so

$$ba + b(-a) = 0.$$

You can immediately conclude that $b(-a) = -ba$. If you know that multiplication is commutative (I don't know whether this fact has been introduced at this point in the text you're following), then this implies $(-a)b = -ab$ as you stated (but you may want to point out the use of commutativity). If you know that multiplication on the right distributes over addition, you can avoid this issue by considering $[a + (-a)]b = 0$ instead.

Comment: Thank you. Now I need to find a way to prove distributive law of multiplication over subtraction.